# divide a single image background acrross multiple divs with different heights

Tags: html, css

Look at the snippet below, I have divs which are clipping the background. I have used table display css property. But I want to those divs to have different heights. I can't use table because every table-cell would have same height. I want those divs to have different heights.

```css
.blocks {
    display:table-row;
}

.block {
    display:table-cell;
    height:100px;
    border:15px solid #FFF;
}

#background-container { 
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538867468559-b14ead85b729?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="background-container">
    <div class="blocks">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="blocks">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blocks">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blocks">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea where you apply the background to a pseudo element and you position it relatively to the main container then you clip the overlow.

Using the below, you can have different width/height for your elements:

```css
.block {
  height: 100px;
  width: 18%;
  flex-grow:1;
  margin:15px;
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#fff 0 0); /* hide the overflow */
}

/* the same background applied to all */
.block::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538867468559-b14ead85b729?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80) center/cover;
}
/**/

#background-container {
  position: relative; /* relative here */
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="background-container">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

A CSS grid configuration is also suitable here:

```css
.block {
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#fff 0 0); /* hide the overflow */
}
.block:nth-child(odd) {
  grid-row:span 2;
}

/* the same background applied to all */
.block::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538867468559-b14ead85b729?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80) center/cover;
}
/**/

#background-container {
  position: relative; /* relative here */
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(4,1fr);
  grid-auto-rows:50px;
  grid-gap:15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="background-container">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you suggest a method without psuedo elements?? @TemaniAfif